# Passing by reference vs by value in Java

Tags: java, c++, c, parameter-passing

I am coming from C/C++ world. I noticed in many posts that people do not accept to say that in Java there is "pass by reference" (for non-primitives); their argument is that, in this case, a copy of the reference is taken. I could not understand this justification since this is actually what happens in C when we pass by reference (a copy of the pointer is taken). For my little understanding in Java, I would say:

- Primitive types are passed by value.
- Non primitive types are passed by reference.

Am I wrong?

Comment: As far as I understand, speaking to a C or C++ programmer I would say that object pointers are passed by value, so in function you can modify the original object, but you can not overwrite the original reference to it.  But I have practically 0 knowledge in Java.

Comment: In this strict sense of the word, C doesn't have pass by reference *either.* It has "pass by pointer," just like Java. This is in contrast to C++, which has genuine pass by referece.

Comment: Thanks. You are very true. C has no pass by reference. Now I understand the difference Java vs C vs C++.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In C++, consider the function: `void func(Type &arg);`. Here, if you change `arg` (not the *contents of arg* but the actual variable), the caller's view of the passed in argument has changed -- completely. This is pass by reference. Contrast that with `void func(Type *arg);`. Here, you can change the contents of `arg` but if you assign `arg` to something, it's a local change only, due to pass-by-value of a pointer.

In Java, you're using pass by (invisible) pointer on all complex types.

Comment: "(invisible)" It's not invisible. It's just that the syntax for object pointers is different in Java.